# Create wifi hosptot but AP mode not supported

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I want to create a wifi hotspot on my laptop, but AP mode is not supported.

`iw list`:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
```

I suppose I need to change my driver. However, I am unable to find the correct driver for my pc.

`lspci | grep -i Network`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Please help me in finding new driver that supports AP mode or is there any way I can create wifi hotspot without changing my driver?

Comment: Often, AP mode is a hardware issue, not a software/driver issue.

Comment: @Daniel I have dual boot and I create hotspot on windows everyday. How can it be a hardware issue?

Comment: If it works in Windows, then you probably just need to bridge the connection from ethernet to wifi, and then set up a wifi ad hoc network

Comment: @Daniel how to do that?

Comment: In the GUI you can create a bridge.  I would look for another question on that if I were you.  I'm sure that has been answered here already.

Comment: @Daniel: Ok it may work but then I won't be unable to connect my phone and my tablet.

Comment: You should be able to do both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26219/discussion-between-arby-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

You need the brcsmac open source driver instead of broadcom-wl. See [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers).