# Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 simultaneous WiFi + Access point

Tags: networking, drivers, intel-wireless, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I mean to have my laptop under Ubuntu 16.04LTS as both an Access Point and using it also to connect to internet (e.g., browsing).
I found that [this is possible](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device).
I would need

```
$ iw list    
Wiphy phy0
...
        Supported interface modes:
                 ...
                 * AP
```

but in my case

```
$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
...
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * monitor
```

I have a

```
$ lspci | grep -i Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
$ ethtool -i wlp3s0 | grep driver
driver: iwlwifi
```

From the many references that I read, I wasn't clear about a few points:

1. **Does my card support AP per se?** According to [this](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/centrino-ultimate-n-6300-brief.pdf) and 
   [this](https://communities.intel.com/thread/34033), the card is capable of using Intel® My WiFi Dashboard, so it would support AP.
2. **Is it mandatory to have AP mode supported by the driver?**
   According to [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/wifi-hotspot-access-point-not-supported/), `iwlwifi`, what I have, would be ok, so I would already have hardware and drivers supporting AP mode (but there is something clearly missing).
3. **Can I change to [Broadcom driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652333/create-wifi-hosptot-but-ap-mode-not-supported) to get the AP mode?** (I did not dare trying, lest ruining my current wifi access and getting none).
4. **Must I install ap-hotspot or [create_ap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251296/137608)?**

Comment: Installing a Broadcom driver for your Intel wireless device will neither help nor hurt. It will simply waste time.

Comment: @chili555 - Ok. And regarding the other points?

Comment: I am not sure, but if your card and driver combination doesn't report that it supports AP mode, then I'm not sure there is anything else you can do, aside from replacing the card. My Intel 7260 reports: Supported interface modes:
   * IBSS
   * managed
   * AP
   * AP/VLAN
   * monitor
   * P2P-client
   * P2P-GO
   * P2P-device